# Суммирование по элементу массива в Mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Есть коллекция с такой схемой

```
...
{ "_id" : ObjectId("579fc863d246f4640173d0b4"),
  "flow" : [ 178488283, NumberLong("4294967295"), NumberLong("4294967295"),
     11, 0, 2, 264,
     1470073539, 1470073539, 48471, 5678, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  "sequence" : 64754, "sensor" :  "192.168.236.1" }
...
```

Как мне просуммировать по flow.6 ?

```
db.collector.aggregate( 
  [{ $group: { _id: 'rx' , bytes : { $sum : 'flow.6' }, count : { $sum :1 }}}] )
```

выдает вот..

```
{ "_id" : "rx", "bytes" : 0, "count" : 151291 }
```

Менять массив на словарь???

Comment: Какая версия MongoDB?

Comment: на 3,2 начинал. сейчас структура поменялась и интересно пройтись немного подругому

Comment: Нужно еще ответ?) Есть лучше способь это делать если у вас стоит 3.2.

Comment: ответы на so всегда нужны. я часто нахожу то что нужно не в ответе с галкой. потихоньку переношу все добро на 3,4 - думаю они релизнут свою базу к моему релизу

Answer (score 1):

$unwind раскрывает массив, вот это уже ближе к правде:

```
> db.collector.aggregate( [ {$unwind: "$flow" },
 { $group: { _id: 'rx' , bytes : { $sum : 6 }, count : { $sum :1 }}}] )
{ "_id" : "rx", "bytes" : 17328276, "count" : 2888046 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нам не нужно использовать оператор `$unwind` здесь. Нужно группировать документы по выбранному полю и использовать оператор `$arrayElemAt` для доступа к шестому элементу в массиве.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
        "_id": "rx", 
        "bytes": {"$sum": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$flow", 5]}},
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }}
])
```